# What's the correct way to handle an article standfirst in WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, styling, custom-fields

I'm new to magazine publishing and am working on a WordPress site in this area. Each of our articles has a coverline, a headline, a standfirst, and article text. The coverline (post title) and article text (post text) are well supported by WordPress, but the headline and standfirst are not. Before I came on board, our post authors were copy-pasting headline and standfirst styling from a word processor. The word processor inserted `<span style="font-size: 34px; font-family:...">` tags to apply styling.

When we changed the website over to a new theme and a new set of fonts, of course the styling of all the headlines and standfirsts did not follow.

While I can fix old article styling with regex replace, we need to do this properly going forward.

I've been asked to set up dynamic styling for headlines and standfirsts, but I think just adding a couple CSS classes is not the solution here. This is because my post authors are non-technical people, and they're not willing to go into the code view of a post and insert, for example, `<div class="standfirst"></div>` tags around every standfirst.

Is this a job for a custom field plugin? I would like to do this the 'right' way for them, so that they don't have to do it all over again in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The headline could be styled within the editor.

Just use the paragraph styling for this, and give it a heading 2 or 3.

The lead paragraph could be styled by

```
p:first-of-type { font-weight: bold /* or other styling */}
```

You could chose to give the editors the option of styling it by placing  or  tags arround it which could be initialised by the bold and italic buttons in the editor

Or you could give custom classes to different paragraphs by adding them to the editor. Read more about that here: https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Styles

Comment: Perfect, I'd forgotten about first-of-type! We're now using h2:first-of-type to style the headline, and i:first-of-type for the standfirst. All my authors need to do is click Heading 2 for the headline, click Italic for the standfirst, and go!

Comment: It seemed good until we put it in practice...the WordPress 'italicize' command in the visual editor (and ctrl+i) incorrectly place <em> tags instead of <i> tags around the standfirst. Our articles are full of a mixture of <em> and <i>. So, CSS identifying `em:first-of-type, i:first-of-type` almost always styles undesired text (as well as the desired text). I cannot further limit the standfirst styling to `p:first-of-type` because several authors don't insert paragraph tags around it. The problem seems so easy but we are stumped again...

Comment: Wordpress automatically adds P tags. So you don't have to worry about that. Maybe education is the solution here ... Or use a echo str_replace(array('<em>','</em>'),array('<i>','</i>', get_the_content() );